# ControleTemplate в ResourceDicitionary wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, триггер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно установить код ControleTamplate в словарь ресурсов:

```
<Window x:Class="Проверка_ошибки_Автозаполнение.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Проверка_ошибки_Автозаполнение"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MVVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DGR" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  AllEmployee}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <local:MyDataGridColumnName Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="150"/>
            <local:MyDataGridColumnUnit Header="SecondName" Binding="{Binding SecondName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
 public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}

public class MVVM : Employee
{
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> allEmployee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> AllEmployee
    {
        get { return allEmployee; }
        set { allEmployee = value; }
    }

    public MVVM()
    {
        allEmployee.CollectionChanged += OnItemsCollectionChanged;
    }
    private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (Employee item in e.NewItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (Employee item in e.OldItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Strings");
    }

    public void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == Name)
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Strings");
    }
}
```

}

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Проверка_ошибки_Автозаполнение">
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CellTemplateName">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Введите Имя: " x:Name="textBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CellTemplateUnit">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Введите Фамилия: " x:Name="textBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Забыл дописать

```
<Application x:Class="Проверка_ошибки_Автозаполнение.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Проверка_ошибки_Автозаполнение"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
 public class MyDataGridColumnName : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            return base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

        var window = Window.GetWindow(cell);
        var template = (ControlTemplate)window.Resources["CellTemplateName"];
        var control = new Control { Template = template };
        return control;
    }
}
public class MyDataGridColumnUnit : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            return base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

        var window = Window.GetWindow(cell);
        var template = (ControlTemplate)window.Resources["CellTemplateUnit"];
        var control = new Control { Template = template };
        return control;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Странный подход, но да ладно... Что в данном варианте не так?

Comment: Я не знаю может я неправильно что то делаю, я пробовал вариант в Windows.Resources устанавливать, он работает всё без проблем, но так как я хотел бы убрать его в отдельное место (это место Resources.Dictionary) и в этом случае выдает ошибку.

Comment: Вы вроде не новичок на SO, а вопросы до сих пор не информативные. Нам самим проверять какая ошибка и как это работает все? Или все же отредактируете, добавив всю необходимую информацию в вопрос?

Comment: Думал так проще, сейчас соберу весь код вместе и исправлю вопрос

Comment: Вот я добавил файл - ResourceDictionary, в нем прописал весь указанный вами код. Сам словарь указал в App и в основном окне на кнопку задал шаблон `<Button Template="{StaticResource CellTemplatePosition }"/>`. Все работает. Так что ваш вопрос пока мне не понятен...

Comment: Прошу прощения снимаю вопрос, сейчас отдельно код составил, всё работает!!!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87355/discussion-between--and-evgeniyz).